# Search for empty spaces in list template

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to search a list (template) and check if the list contains spaces. If there are spaces then I want to remove them from the list.

```
list <char> L1;

if (!L1.empty())
{

    for (auto f = L1.begin(); f != L1.end(); ++f)
    {
        if (f == " ")
            L1.remove(f);
    }
}
```

> Error: IntelliSense: no `operator "=="` matches these operands
>               operand types are: `std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<char>>> == const char`

How do I implement this?

Comment: `L1.remove(' ');` does the job.

Comment: `" "` != `' '`, C-string versus char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 issues in your code:

1. `f` is an iterator. To access the value to compare it you need to dereference the iterator `*f`.
2. your list contains single characters you should therefore compare to the space character `' '` rather than the string containing a single space `" "`
3. [`std::list::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) takes a value not an iterator, you need [`std::list::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase)
4. after removing an element you need to be careful how you use your iterator, you need to use the iterator returned from erase

The corrected code is:

```
if (!L1.empty())
{
    for (auto f = L1.begin(); f != L1.end();)
    {
        if (*f == ' ')
        {
            f = L1.erase(f);
        }
        else
        {
            ++f;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `std::list` has this functionality built in so you can just call

```
L1.remove(' ');
```

P.S. don't trust the errors from intellisense they are better than they used to be but still not 100% reliable, always compile your code to get the true error message.

Answer (score 0):

f in your code is an iterator which points to an element in your list L1. Iterators are just some fancy pointers behind, so if you want to acces the element pointed at by your iterator you can just use `*f`.

Thus your code should be:
    list  L1;

```
if (!L1.empty())
{

    for (auto f = L1.begin(); f != L1.end();)
    {
        if (*f == ' ')
            L1.remove(f);
        else
            ++f;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Also as pointed out by @paler123, you should change the double quotes to apostrophes, since quotes are used for char array and apostrophes for chars.

One more note, when you are removing an element from L1 by using an iterator, the iterator gets incremented automatically(pointing to the next element) and the it gets incremented again by the for, so you are skipping one element.

Comment: Not quite, list elements are chars, so single quotes should be used in comparison.